# When do we write numbers with letters?

Tags: numbers

The only place where I had to write *218* with "ducent dek ok" was in Lernu! and Duolingo. I never had to write any number in letters outside of a learning course. When people can write "dek sepa", they often write *17a*, since it is probably quicker to read.

Comment: Most likely, English convention dictates - if it can be represented with one word, you spell it, and if it can't, you use the digits.

Comment: Shouldn't that be *17-a* (with a dash)?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev I have seen both and there are no rules about that, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In official documents, for big amounts, you use numbers and letters, to avoid mistakes (while reading or writing).
For example, when you sell your house, it's better to write something like:
EUR 234000 (ducent tridek kvar mil eŭroj)
(if you forget writing a zero, we are sure there is a mistake)

Answer (score 4):

Here are the rules of the magazine MONATO. They are based on the actual use:

Nombrojn de nulo ĝis dek oni skribas per literoj, se ne temas pri decimaloj. Oni skribas per ciferoj la pli altajn kvantojn: *ses-cilindra motoro, dek eŭroj* sed *inter la 11 unuaj, oni vendis 16 450 ekzemplerojn*.
Pro kohereco oni skribas ĉiujn kvantojn de la sama serio per ciferoj, se almenaŭ unu estas pli granda ol dek: *5 libroj, 9 kajeroj kaj 15 skribiloj*.